# insert records do not show up in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using python to perform basic ETL to transfer records from a mysql database to a postgres database.  I am using python to commence the tranfer:

### python code

```
  source_cursor = source_cnx.cursor()
  source_cursor.execute(query.extract_query)
  data = source_cursor.fetchall()
  source_cursor.close()

  # load data into warehouse db
  if data:
    target_cursor = target_cnx.cursor()
    #target_cursor.execute("USE {};".format(datawarehouse_name))
    target_cursor.executemany(query.load_query, data)
    print('data loaded to warehouse db')
    target_cursor.close()
  else:
    print('data is empty')
```

### MySQL Extract (extract_query):

```
SELECT `tbl_rrc`.`id`,
   `tbl_rrc`.`col_filing_operator`,
   `tbl_rrc`.`col_medium`,
   `tbl_rrc`.`col_district`,
   `tbl_rrc`.`col_type`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`tbl_rrc`.`col_timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f') as `col_timestamp` 
from `tbl_rrc`
```

### PostgreSQL (loading_query)

```
INSERT INTO geo_data_staging.tbl_rrc
    (id,
    col_filing_operator,
    col_medium,
    col_district,
    col_type,
    col_timestamp)
    VALUES
    (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);
```

Of note, there is a PK constraint on Id.

The problem is while I have no errors, I'm not seeing any of the records in the target table.  I tested this by manually inserting a record, then running again.  The code errored out violating PK constraint.  So I know it's finding the table.

Any idea on what I could be missing, I would be greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Are you committing the `INSERT` transaction?

Comment: apparently not.  Thanks much... please put this as an answer so I can give you points.  I come from a SQL Server background, so I didn't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `psycopg2`, you have to call `commit()` on your cursors in order for transactions to be committed. If you just call `close()`, the transaction will implicitly roll back.

There are a couple of exceptions to this. You can set the connection to autocommit. You can also [use your cursors inside a `with` block](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement), which will automatically commit if the block doesn't throw any exceptions.

Comment: Thanks much!  It's really appreciated.